# How to know user has entered wrong password to unlock iPhone?

Tags: iphone

How can I know from my iPhone application that "user has entered wrong password to unlock iPhone?" Is there any Delegate or event that occurs when user has entered wrong password to unlock iPhone?

Comment: Why do you need to know ? We may be able to suggest an alternative ?

Comment: i wants make application in which when user entered wrong password to unlock iPhone, then front camera be will take picture of user.please give me suggestion for my application

Comment: You wont be abel to do it like this. The way I think other apps do it is recreate a lock screen view in their app to look like the iOS one.

Comment: thanks for reply me.but my requirement is that i wants to take picture of that user who are entering wrong password to unlock **iPhone**?

Comment: You cannot achieve this through the use of the iPhones native lock screen. You need to create your own app to implement this behaviour. Have you looked at one of the many apps on the store that do this ? This will give you an idea of what to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no public API for checking this.